# MS Bots, Hero Card button to call method within bot?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bots, botframework

I need to the button attached to the hero card to call back a method I have within the backend.
now I guess I need to use postBack as button type , but how can I make it call a specific method and pass a parameter along.
my button look like :

```
   CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
                    {
                        Value = I need to pass the method here !?,
                        Type = "postBack",
                        Title = "Show Delivery Locations"
                    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is to use the postBack method type as you have done and pass a unique string like a guid (something that the user would never tell me) and identify that string in my waterfall and call the proper method from there.  Passing args would be hard as you would have to embed them within the string and parse it on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html) document from Microsoft.
If you want to hide response message the postBack type is the right choice, otherwise imBack is valid too.

The way you recognize the answer depends on how you manage the conversation. I suggest you take a look at [LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/home/index)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more graceful way to do this might be to use the "dialogAction" functionality for a CardAction. You can use it in conjunction with a dialog's *beginDialogAction* action. That way you could pass additional data to whichever dialog you want to be triggered.

Here's a [link](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.cardaction.html#dialogaction) to the Botbuilder NodeJS SDK referencing the same. I'm sure there must be something similar for C# too.